# How to implement autoscroll horizontal listView (or view) supports onClick() (or onItemClick()) on each item (or view)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need a widget like a horizontal images slider that scroll from right to left automatically. When I click on a image (an item) I retrieve full-size activity contains the image.

Customizing Android UI widgets/APIs is interesting and hard for me.

Can you give me the implementation and I use it as "black-box"?

Comment: use Dev-smart Library for horizontal list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try RecyclerView

It has horizontal scroll

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Gallery or ViewSwitcher class, it makes your case easier to do.